# how to delete field property of document in Elasticsearch using java？

Tags: elasticsearch

I hava a document in Elasticsearch：

```
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "class": "aaa",
        "id": 1,
        "items": [{
            "class": "aaa",
            "id": 1
        },{
            "class": "ccc",
            "id": 2
        }],
        "lastUpdated": "2016-07-22T11:26:56Z",
        "processInstance": {
            "class": "bbb"
        },
        "bianhao": "123"
    }
}
```

how to delete `id` or `class` of `items` using java?
how to delete `{"class": "ccc","id": 2}` using java?

I know how to delete a field,using:

```
client.prepareUpdate("test", "document", "1")
        .setScript(new Script(
                "ctx._source.remove(\"bianhao\")",
                ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE, null, null))
        .get();
```

the content of `items` is json array,I have not found the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("classParam", "ccc");
params.put("idParam", 2);

client.prepareUpdate("test", "document", "1")
    .setScript(new Script(
            "ctx._source.items.removeAll{ it['class'] == classParam && it.id == idParam }",
            ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE, null, params))
    .get();
```

Comment: Is there    `replaceAll() `method?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: change `{"class": "ccc","id": 2}` to `{"class": "ccc12","id": 2}`

Comment: I suggest you create another question as this is a different issue from the topic of this question.

Comment: I asked a new question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782947/how-to-change-field-property-of-document-in-elasticsearch-using-java