# how to change field property of document in Elasticsearch using java？

Tags: elasticsearch

I hava a document in Elasticsearch：

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "document",
  "_id": "1",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
      "class": "aaa",
      "id": 1,
      "items": [{
          "class": "aaa",
          "id": 1
      }, {
          "class": "ccc",
          "id": 2
      }],
      "bianhao": "123"
  } 
}
```

I want to replace `{"class": "ccc","id": 2}` of `items` with  `{"class": "ccc12","id": 2}`,how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("idParam", 2);
params.put("classParam", "ccc12");

client.prepareUpdate("test", "document", "1")
    .setScript(new Script(
            "ctx._source.items.find{ it.id == idParam }['class'] = classParam",
            ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE, null, params))
    .get();
```

**UPDATE**

And if you want to change multiple fields, you can do it like this:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("idParam", 2);
params.put("classParam", "ccc12");
params.put("field1Param", "value2");
params.put("field2Param", "value3");

client.prepareUpdate("test", "document", "1")
    .setScript(new Script(
            "def item = ctx._source.items.find{ it.id == idParam}; if (item) {item['class'] = classParam; item['field1'] = field1Param; item['field2'] = field2Param}",
            ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE, null, params))
    .get();
```

Comment: In this case,firstly find 'id' then set value to 'class'.I mean if there are many fields,`{"id": 2,"class":"ccc","name":"dddd","field1":"value1","field1":"value2"}`,how to replace them once?

Comment: Do you want to change multiple fields?

Comment: This problem has been bothering me for serval days.Can you help me out ？@Val  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886939/add-highlight-does-not-work-with-has-child-query-in-elasticsearch-2-3-3